# Streaming local encrypted file to Apple TV

Tags: ios, encryption

My app solution on iOS has downloaded audio and video for offline use. Streaming to apple tv worked like charm for a while, however, we needed to implement file encryption. As a web app, to support encrypted file on the webview, we implemented a http server, which decrypts the file, and streams it unencrypted to the webview request. But now, we need to stream theses encrypted files to the Apple Tv, obviously, when trying to shared the video/audio, the Apple TV tries to stream from the iPad http server url (`localhost:8000`), and an error is shown.

How should I be able to stream it? As I see, there are other apps which uses encryption and works fine with air play.

Edit: The error message is way generic, just appears on TV that the file could not be played, no log on xcode console.

The HTML on the `webview` is simple as that, no big deal: `<video src= "http://localhost:8000/file/fileId"/>`, works fine on iPad, but not streaming to Apple TV.

Comment: Could you post your code, for this piece, thus far?  Also, what is the error message?

Comment: Edited question with more info.